# Get Value from JTextArea in Another Class

Tags: java

Here's the problem. I had to fill a `TextArea` in Class B (`tAreaB`) with a value from `TextArea` in Class A (`tAreaA`).

I'm doing this in Class A:

```
tAreaA.setText("Value A");
```

How can I fill the `tAreaB` with same value as `tAreaA`?
I have tried this in ClassB:

```
String value;
ClassA a = new ClassA();
value = a.tAreaA.getText();
tAreaB.setText(value);
```

Comment: Assuming you have access to both instances of the class and that the classes provide the means to pass the required information, your problem basically boils down to [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html). The problem is, there's very little context available in your question to provide a suitable answer. How ever, I believe you thinking in a linear/procedural manner instead of a event driven one which may explain your primary issues

Comment: If what you are trying to do is to sync tAreaB with tAreaA at all time you have to implement an event listener. Your code works if you are just setting the text at that time.

Comment: but it's not work. It's only get a blank value. Can i post my whole code? I'm just trying to make the question simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you know how works methods, so, the only thing that you need to do is very simple...

Code:

```
//Class A - button's - ActionListener.
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent A){

//Create a empty variable: String, with the name of: value.
String value = "";

//Value, gets the text of the: txtAreaA.
value = txtAreaA.getText();

//Calls the: classB, and create a new object from them.
classB cb = new classB();

//cb.txtAreaB(); is the method who creates a: JFrame, with JTextArea, in classB.
cb.txtAreaB();

//Now, just call the object, and set the text: value.
cb.txtAreaB.setText(value);
}});
```

Comment: I tried your code. In System.out.println, it did get the value. But, the textarea didn't get the value.

Comment: The Class B I made is an extends of JPanel. Is that matter?

Comment: I solved it. I change Class B from extends JPanel to extends JFrame.

Comment: Sure, no problem, in my case, in: Class B, I used a simple JFrame with a JTextArea inside it... Not matters if you use a JPanel, JFrame, or whatever that you wants. 

If my answer helps to solve your issue, please place it as useful.